# How do I play sound when app begins windows phone

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone, mediaelement

On my windows phone app, I want to play a short .wav audio, similar to windows when it boots up. At first I tried using an event handler when one of my controls was loaded (this worked about 60% of the time, which is very interesting, maybe someone can clear that up as well, I'm thinking it has to do with the order things happen to load. That's why its different each time running it). I'm using visual studios 2012 ultimate, this is my xaml code for the .wav file:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MySound"
                          Source="/quantum_drive.wav"
                          Volume="1"
                          AutoPlay="false"
                          />
```

I've also just tried to call this method when the main page loads:

```
private void MainPage1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySound.Play();
    }
```

For some reason this only works about 60% of the time(seemingly randomly), why is this?! This seems like a common thing to want to do in a phone app, yet I cannot find any information on this on stackoverflow or google searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the media element to do what you are trying to do. It is to buggy for sound effects. It is meant more for user interaction media.

Instead, do the following ([you can the full article here](http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=60))

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

static Stream stream1 = TitleContainer.OpenStream("soundeffect.wav");

static SoundEffect sfx = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream1);

static SoundEffectInstance soundEffect = sfx.CreateInstance();
```

Now just invoke play sound from your loaded method

```
public void playSound(){

    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

    soundEffect.Play();

}
```

Comment: When I add the namespaces it says that the namespace "Xna" does not exist in the namespace Microsoft. Is this specific to Windows phone 8.0? I built this as a Windows Phone App targeting 7.1.

Comment: No what that means is that you need to add the reference to your solution. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: Gotcha. So I implemented this code, and now what is happening is when i first run the app (with the emulator closed before bebugging so it has to load up) it plays the sound; But for each time I run it afterwards(without closing the emulator) it only plays the sound a fraction of the time. It actually seems to be having the same sort of buggy randomness as the mediaElements were. Why is this? Also, I had to remove the keywords "static" from the code, compiler was complaining about those.

Comment: Honestly without sitting at your comp and seeing what you are doing it is hard to determine what you are talking about. Odds are you are implementing it wrong or miss interpreting what is happening on your machine. Do not forget to test this on an actual device as well. You could be experiencing issues related to debuging on an emulator.