# Playing sound when sms composer is opened in C#

Tags: c#

I am writing an app for windows phone 8.1 which sends sms using the following code:

```
 Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage msg = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage();
            msg.Body = "Help! I am in danger! ";
            msg.Recipients.Add(App.CNum1.ToString());
            msg.Recipients.Add(App.CNum2.ToString());
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(msg);
```

I also need a beep sound to be played whenever the sms composer is opened but I don't know how to put MediaElement on the composer. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This is not what I need. I just want to play a sound when the sms composer is opened in windows phone 8.1

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736357/how-do-i-play-sound-when-app-begins-windows-phone